# Can Allah forgive third party

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness, doubts

I have wronged a lot of people and I don’t want to tell them because I feel like we will be enemies and it will ruin their lives can I make dua for them will Allah forgive me? Please help me I’m too young and I’m already scared :( I feel remorse and I fear the punishment waiting for me but I also know that Allah is most merciful and when I heard this it gives the hope. And it makes me happy and worried at the same time I just want to move on in my life and be a good and better Muslim.

Comment: You can make Dua for them I would say if telling them could lead into a bigger problem then do not tell them.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/6308/forgiveness-of-victim-of-gossip

Comment: So no matter what kind of third party it is if I make dua and still have hope in the mercy of Allah do I have a chance to be forgiven

Comment: Allah the most merciful his mercy best his punishment. Check the link I provided. And yes you will be forgiven did you read the ayah: 
 إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَغْفِرُ أَن يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ ذَٰلِكَ لِمَن يَشَاءُ ۚ وَمَن يُشْرِكْ بِاللَّهِ فَقَدِ افْتَرَىٰ إِثْمًا عَظِيمًا
Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assalam o Allaikum bro.

First of all, I would like to appreciate you to even think that way.

Now coming to your question. Try to confront those people with all your heart and pray to Allah that they forgive you. Because no matter what we do, Allah doesn't forgive us person until or unless that person forgives us whom we wronged.

Once Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) was asked by the Sahabah Do you know who a bankrupt person is? They said the bankrupt among us is the person who does not have any wealth. Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) said, “*The bankrupt person is someone who comes on the day of judgement with many rewards, prayer, fasting, Zakat, but he had accused a person falsely, he abused another, cursed a third, taken the money of somebody else, spilt the blood of someone else, so he ends up giving them from his good deeds and if he runs out of good deeds and he didn’t pay them back, then they start giving him some of their sins and he ends up going to hell fire.* - Sahih Muslim

If there is a sin committed by us then it's between us and Allah and Allah can forgive us, but if there is a sin committed between us and someone else, then that has to be sorted out between the two.

Allah says in the Quran, "*The recompense for an evil is an evil like thereof; but whoever forgives and makes reconciliation, his reward is with Allah. Verily, He likes not the oppressors.*" [42:40]

If you have done this out of being oblivious to the fact that it is a sin, then Inshallah, Allah will pardon you. The fact that you have changed and are attempting to fix things that you had done in the past shows that Allah has blessed you with the goodness of character.

The best way is to talk to them directly and speak to them from your heart and ask for forgiveness. May Allah softens their hearts and they shall understand that you indeed have changed. But if you still think that confronting them will make things worse then the best tool you have is dua. Try to make dua for her daily without skipping a day and it will connect you to her in a beautiful, spiritual way. Allah will bless both of you, and you never know, what the power of dua will bring your way!